# Generating Random Integer Values

Tags: c, random, generator

In short I'm looking for a concise algorithm for generating sudorandom numbers in C that I can assign as Integer Values. I would also like to be able to assign a max value limit for generation.

Comment: Is there any reason [`rand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) won't work for you?

Answer (score -1):

This is a useful function you could use I made!

```
int getRandomNumber(int max)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int number = r.Next(0, max);
    return number;
}
```